# Execution monad

Tags: monads, scalding

I know monad is the general concept. What about Execution monad. Is it a general concept or design Patten which can be used outside scalding too.

I have seen new version of scalding is having execution monads.

Answer (score 1):

It is just one specific monad, which is part of scalding.  So, not a general concept.

You could use similar monads in other contexts outside of scalding, but the exact monad would be different, and the term "execution monad" doesn't seem to be commonly used except to refer specifically to the scalding execution monad.