# Scalding Execution Monad - What is it & how to use it

Tags: scala, bigdata, scalding

I am working on Big Data technologies using MR based on Java. But recently my company has moved to Scalding framework. I am not able get my head around the Scalding Execution Monad. What it is and how it works. Cannot find much material on it on internet as well. Would somebody please throw some light on it.
Also trying to understand the ExecutionContext.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510896/execution-monad

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/tutorial/Execution.md
Is anything still unclear?

Comment: Hi Dima, Yes i have gone through the above linke many many times but not able to understand ..how Execution is being used to schedule and run a Hadoop job..esp using the fromFuture and from ...i need an example to understand it. Also i have tried to find about in youtube but didnt find any resource. If someone has worked on previously kindly throw some light.